# Adding draggable box into same div as first box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, append

Hey all I am trying my best to get this current code working. I am trying to create a new *draggabilly* box inside the **existing** box so that I can add an unlimited amount of boxes.

However, currently it seems to place the second box **outside** the original box that the first box is in.

The [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/rrg9rmrn/4/) demo is here for you.

The main part of the javascript code is:

```
$('#buttonPush').on('click', function(e) {
   var _tmpLabelBox = "fakeLabel" + fakeCount;

   if (fakeCount == 0) {
     $('body').append('<div id="thePDFPage">' +
       '<div id="' + _tmpLabelBox + '" contenteditable="true" data-type="labelBox" data-posxy="0,0" class="fakeLabel">' +
       '<div class="handle" contenteditable="false"></div>' +
       '&nbsp;' +
       '</div>' +
       '</div>');
   } else {
     $('body').append('<div id="' + _tmpLabelBox + '" contenteditable="true" data-type="labelBox" data-posxy="0,0" class="fakeLabel">' +
       '<div class="handle" contenteditable="false"></div>' +
       '&nbsp;' +
       '</div>');
   }

   $("#" + _tmpLabelBox).on('keydown', function(e) {
     e = e || event;
     var code = e.which || e.keyCode || e.charCode;
     var cando = !([46, 13].indexOf(code) > -1);

     if (code == 8) {
       if ($(this).text().length == 0) {
         return false;
       } else {
         return cando;
       }
     } else {
       return cando;
     }
   });

   $("#" + _tmpLabelBox).resizable({
     containment: "#thePDFPage",
     grid: 5,
     autoHide: true,
     handles: "e",
     stop: function(event, ui) {
       //$(ui.element).height('auto');
     }
   });

   $("#" + _tmpLabelBox).autoresize({
     padding: 10,
     minWidth: 50,
     maxWidth: 300
   });

   $('#' + _tmpLabelBox).draggabilly({
     handle: '.handle',
     containment: true,
     grid: [5, 5]
   });

   $('#' + _tmpLabelBox).on('click', function() {
     $('div.selected').removeClass('selected');
     $(this).addClass('selected');
   }).keydown(function(e) {
     var div = $('div.selected');
     switch (e.which) {
       case 37:
         div.stop().animate({
           left: '-=5'
         });
         break;
       case 38:
         div.stop().animate({
           top: '-=5'
         });
         break;
       case 39:
         div.stop().animate({
           left: '+=5'
         });
         break;
       case 40:
         div.stop().animate({
           top: '+=5'
         });
         break;
     }
   });

   $('#' + _tmpLabelBox).on('dragEnd', function(event, pointer, moveVector) {
     var _tmpDragElement = $(this).data('draggabilly');

     $(this).attr('data-posXY', _tmpDragElement.position.x + "," + _tmpDragElement.position.y);
   });

   callWysiwyg(_tmpLabelBox);
   fakeCount++;
})
```

I'm not really sure what all I am missing in order to place it into the save DIV as the first box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a `div` with an `id` of `thePDFPage` which contains a `wysiwyg-container`. This container is where you're finally adding the "draggable" item. In the `else` portion of your code, all subsequent items must be added to `wysiwyg-container`.

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/rrg9rmrn/5/)**

Comment: Thanks for the help, Yass.

Comment: Did you notice the extra textbox it creates after the 3rd click of the button (below the area)?

Comment: I did, but I wasn't sure what the problem was. I'll take a look when I have some time.

Comment: Any luck about why its doing that? I haven't been able to determine why either.

Comment: Not sure. Your code is quite messy so it's hard to decipher what's going on.